# Hibernate Duplicate entry for pirmarky key of referenced entity on using composite primary key and @MapsId

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the following entities  and is using hibernate 4.1.* as the JPA provider but using an composite primary key in customer table which maps to the user gives me
**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry  for key 'PRIMARY'**

The entities mappings are as below.

```
@Entity
class Customer {
@EmbeddedId CustomerId id;
boolean preferredCustomer;

@MapsId("userId")
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "first_name_", referencedColumnName = "first_name"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "last_name", referencedColumnName = "last_name")
    })
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private User user;
  -----
 }

 @Embeddable
 private UserPK userId;

  @Basic(optional = false)
  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "customer_number")
 private int customerNumber;
  ----
}

@Entity 
class User {
 @EmbeddedId UserId id;
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @NotNull
 @Column(name = "age")
 private int age;  
 ------
 }

@Embeddable
class UserId implements Serializable {     
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @NotNull
 @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
 @Column(name = "first_name")
 private String firstName;
 @Basic(optional = false)
 @NotNull
 @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
 @Column(name = "last_name")
 private String lastName;
-------
  }
```

The same mapping works with eclipselink. Also it works if I remove UserId from CustomerId and just reference it,  but I want to solve this using hibernate and @MapsId

I tried using different cascade option as per the suggestion in [JPA 2 - Foreign key that only includes one field from a composite primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832544/jpa-2-foreign-key-that-only-includes-one-field-from-a-composite-primary-key)   but there was no luck.